# How can I run a custom Cocoa Framework as a scheduled task within CRONTab?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, frameworks, cron

In my OSX application project, I have a custom-made framework. I'm looking for information on how can I create a crontab task that runs it as an scheduled task, every day. Any hints will be very appreciated.

Comment: A framework is a library, not an executable; it can't be run on its own. Can you be more specific as to what you mean here?

Comment: Our framework haves a collection of asynchronous tasks that are used to measure internet connection. Inside the application, it can be used/called without issues, but we must also implement a scheduled task that runs the features within the framework.